# Is it possible to send a request to another user to review my question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Let's say I post a new question about some topic only few people know about.

Is it possible to send a request to specific users (users I guess may know the answer) to have it a check?

Sometimes people post interesting questions but nobody answers it, maybe it is (amongst other reasons) because the right people just never saw it. I think that some approach like this would increase the probability of a question to be answered. Just my guess.

Comment: Think of our most renowned users like Jon Skeet, then think of the amount of people asking for THEIR attention there would be. You'll see why it's a bad idea

Comment: And what if the user can disable somehow the feature to prevent others to send requests to him/her?

Comment: And also limit the amount of users you can request reviews from per question?

Comment: "just never saw" is solved by placing bounty.

Comment: If "topic only few people know about" there is very good chance that those people already watching all questions on that topic. If you have particular cases where you believe it happened you may want to ask with "specific-question" tag here why particular post may not receive enough attention - likely you'll get good recommendations (and/or plenty of downvotes if post shows no research).

Comment: Ok. I see the reasons why not. But let me say that I still think it is a good feature to implement that may help in some cases and SO has all the tools to mitigate even more the negative impacts. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: If you let people opt out of this, how do you plan on notifying the user who tries to ping someone and fail? What's the backup here? (Anyway I can tell you most experts would quickly opt out, so we'd be left with pretty much what we have now).

Comment: When it's not an annoyance to skilled users, it would be a great tool to synchronize voting rings.

Comment: Hmm...actually.. yes.  Implement the feature, wait 6 months, then remove the accounts of all those who still have it enabled :)

Comment: It almost seems as if you're desiring consultative help from specific individuals. In real life you'd have to pay for that type of service.

Answer (score 8):

**No**, and please don't do that.

Even if, as you [mention](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356053/is-it-possible-to-send-a-request-to-another-user-to-review-my-question#comment510445_356053), it would be possible to mitigate the impact on high profile users, we already have very efficient ways to let users know of what might interest them, namely tags and upvotes. Those are the way the system let users choose what they are interested in.

Moreover, do you really think that a beginner in a technology, would be suitably placed to "guess" who would be best suited to answer their question? That beginner would actually be one of the *last* person to be able to take a cool head decision about that.

When nobody answers a question, it is much more likely that people just are not interested in answering it, rather than the "right" people haven't seen it.