# I want to be able to comment in a questions posted but don't have enough reputation points

Tags: discussion

I need help building my website with [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), and I would like to talk to the person who partially answered one of my questions (asked by another user). This question was posted here on Stack Overflow, but for some reason I need 50 points of "reputation" to be able to comment on the post/question.

What can I do to contact this person on Stack Overflow directly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we be able to send private messages to other users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/should-we-be-able-to-send-private-messages-to-other-users)

Comment: Also relevant: [Is it possible to send a request to another user to review my question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/356053/11682469) and the [comment everywhere privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) which explains what comments are for.

Comment: SO is not a social network or a traditional forum. It's a Q&A site in which volunteers build a repository of programming knowledge by asking and answering questions that are supposed to be useful to future visitors.

Comment: *"but for some reason I need 50 points of "reputation" to be able to comment on the post/question"* - the reason is because people tend to misunderstand how Stack Overflow works, so features are opened to them gradually. Commenting is a quite frequently abused system because people want to use it to chat.

Comment: The canonical is *[Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173)*.

Answer (score 6):

If you're sure that your question is [on topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) then simply ask your question as a question in its own right.

The partial answer is your research and you should include the relevant part of that in the question so we know not to repeat it or duplicate your question to that answer.

Once you do that then anyone can answer your question. Perhaps it will be the person you're trying to contact, perhaps someone else. The goal for you is to get an answer, not get an answer from a particular person.